# Scale padding in D3 v 4

Tags: d3.js

[image]

How to make non-padding edge of the x-scale? There is `.rangeBand()` in v3, but I am using D3 v4.

```
var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width], .05).padding(0.1),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);
```

Comment: Maybe you can use `.paddingInner(0.1)` so you don't get padding at the edges...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

You can't anymore.

**Long answer:**

In D3 v4.x there is a `paddingOuter` method for band scales:

> *band*.paddingOuter([padding]):
>
> If padding is specified, sets the outer padding to the specified value which must be in the range **[0, 1]**. If padding is not specified, returns the current outer padding which defaults to 0. The outer padding determines the ratio of the range that is reserved for blank space before the first band and after the last band. (emphasis mine)

However, as you can see, that value goes only from 0 to 1.

Here is a demo with zero outer padding:

```js
var w = 500, h = 100;
var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);
  
var scale = d3.scaleBand()
 .domain("ABCDEFGHIJKL".split(""))
  .range([20, w - 20])
  .paddingOuter(0)
  
var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale);

var gX = svg.append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

And here is another with the maximum (1) outer padding:

```js
var w = 500, h = 100;
var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);
  
var scale = d3.scaleBand()
 .domain("ABCDEFGHIJKL".split(""))
  .range([20, w - 20])
  .paddingOuter(1)
  
var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale);

var gX = svg.append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/issues/102) on GitHub, asking for unlimited outer padding, with a comment from Mike Bostock (D3 creator) in the [pull request](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/pull/101).

**Possible solutions**

Of course, you can download D3 v4 and tweak the band scale function, creating your own function, nothing forbids you. If you want to follow that approach, have a look at the pull request linked above, it just removes `Math.min(1, _)` from the source code.

A way easier solution is this hacky one below: create fake values at the beginning and end of your domain...

```
.domain(["foo", "bar", "baz"].concat(domain).concat(["foobar", "foobaz", "barbaz"]))
```

... and ignore them in the axis:

```
var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
    .tickValues(domain);
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var w = 500, h = 100;
var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);
  
var domain = "ABCDEFGHIJKL".split("")
  
var scale = d3.scaleBand()
 .domain(["foo", "bar", "baz"].concat(domain).concat(["foobar", "foobaz", "barbaz"]))
  .range([20, w - 20]);
  
var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
 .tickValues(domain);

var gX = svg.append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```